# Creating a new rails application, rails new ~path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I run the command `rails new app-path -d postgresql --skip-test`, what does it call my app?

Or is it just the path I put it in?

Comment: Why not give it a go and see what happens? You can always just delete the results if they are not what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a command with `rails new app-path -d postgresql --skip-test` it will create rails app with last part of the `app-path`.

for example
If you run `rails new /Users/apple/work/demo_app -d postgresql --skip-test` it will create app named `demo_app` inside directory `/Users/apple/work`.

If directory specified doesn't exists it will create the path and last part of the path will be app name.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `rails new foo/bar/baz`, the new app will be created inside of `foo/bar/baz` and will be named after the last segment of the provided path, `Baz` in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

if you run "rails new myapp -d mysql", a new folder will be created with the name myapp

if you run  "rails new path/myapp -d mysql", a new folder called "path/myapp" will be created. The project name is myapp